# IBAction from (not to) my custom class

Tags: ios, interface-builder, ibaction

Remember typical situation: we have UIButton, we have some event triggered by something (in our case let it be UITouchUpInside) AND some IBAction somewhere (for example in our UIViewController) that will be called when event occurs. IBAction is created by control-dragging from my button inside my view controller.

Now image another situation: I have some custom class, some event occurs inside it AND I want some IBAction to be performed when my custom event in my custom class occurs. To be more specific, I want to connect object to my view controller in storyboard, then control-drag from one of my events from created object  to my view controller's IBAction (exactly like I did for UIButton and UITouchUpInside). In other words probably I need some kind of selector (?) to be set up from storyboard to call later.

The whole point of all it is to quickly drag from events in my custom class into another place to create (and later call) IBAction, so please do not mention delegation of any form.

Comment: probably better name for my question could be selected, by I can't imagine better, feel free to edit

Comment: If your object is a subclass of UIcontrol then you can call `sendActionsForControlEvents` to trigger the action handlers that have been linked in Interface Builder